# Are there any open source tools to transform postman collections to a client sdk?

Tags: java, rest, api, postman

I am currently in a situation where I have tested some of the APIs provided by a product. I am testing these APIs using postman. I found that [RESTUnited](https://restunited.com) is a tool which can take as an input - postman collection and generates swagger document. And we can use swagger document and generate client-SDK, for example: Java SDK, using which I can later work in Java and write application wrapper on top of it.

My question is this:

Do we have an open source alternative for RESTUnited?
Do we have open source tools to transform postman collections to a client sdk?

Comment: You can try API spark

Comment: thanks @Mohit: I will have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I found this open-source project simple and helpful, you may give it a try: https://github.com/JakeWorrell/docodile

For cloud hosts, updates and maintains documentation for everyone. I'd suggest http://docman.launchrock.com/

Also, the possibility of creating documentation has been added to Postman Cloud, **BUT** a for a *30-day-trial*. Read about it [here](http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/12/10/introducing-postman-cloud/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try https://github.com/stoplightio/api-spec-converter, which is open source (MIT license) and provides expermential support for Postman to Swagger 2.0 conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used [postmantoopenapi.com](https://postmantoopenapi.com) to convert Postman Collections to OpenApi Spec.